# Is there any product/service called Azure DevOps Git?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm looking for an online Git service. GitHub is available from Microsoft. Other than the GitHub, is Microsoft offering any other Git service with Azure DevOps?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

GitHub is a hosting provider for git repositories which was founded in 2008. Microsoft acquired GitHub in 2018. GiiHub now has more features than just hosting repositories.

As GitHub, Micorsoft has it's own Git repository hosting which is the default one if you are using Azure Devops. This is called Azure Debops Git. More information can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/get-started/what-is-repos?view=azure-devops.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [Azure DevOps Server](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/devops/server/), it offers [Azure Repos](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/devops/repos/) to host unlimited private Git repository.